# SOAP java.lang.NullPointerException Error

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I made a research on web but I couldn't find the exact answer for my question. I am trying to make a request to a SOAP service. I can get a proper response when I try with SOAPUI but I can't get anything when I try it with PHP.

Here is a screenshot of SOAPUI: (Backup URL: http://i.hizliresim.com/qGaOOd.png)

[image: SOAP]

Here is my PHP code:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$wsdl = "http://www.estes-express.com/shipmenttracking/services/ShipmentTrackingService?wsdl";

$options = array(
  'auth' => array(
    'user' => 'myuser',
    'password' => 'mypass'
  )
);

$request = array(
  'search' => array(
    'requestID' => '0841824923',
    'pro' => '0841824923'
  )
);



$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($client,true).'</pre>';
try{
    $response = $client->__soapCall('trackShipments', array($request));
    print_r($response);
} catch(SoapFault $ex){
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

print "\n";
```

When I run this script, it returns this error: "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `array($request)` `$request` is already an array, if u already check the connection to the wsdl, maybe is that

Comment: @FranciscoHahn I tried, same result.

Comment: instead of `$response = $client->__soapCall('trackShipments', array($request));
    print_r($response);` go for  `var_dump($client->__getFunctions());`, lets check if ur connection is correct

Comment: @FranciscoHahn I got this: `array(2) { [0]=> string(41) "string echo(EchoRequestType $echoRequest)" [1]=> string(49) "trackingInfo trackShipments(search $trackRequest)" }`

Comment: ok, now try `$response = vardump($client->trackShipments($request));`

Comment: @FranciscoHahn now it says this: `SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'requestID' property`

Comment: yeah, of course its expencting an array, try  `$client->trackShipments(array('search'=>array($request)))`
if im not mistaken its specting a key named search and that search contains an array of requests, but im sure is the variables order
if it does not work try this (cant see the image [it's my intenert connection])  `var_dump($client->trackShipments(array('search' =>array(
    'requestID' => '0841824923',
    'pro' => '0841824923'
  ) )))`

Comment: @FranciscoHahn same result.

Comment: [checkthis](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=storm) its a program to test webservices, why i like it beccause it can show u inmediatelly how u need to pass the object, then u just start to build the array, check it if u can, for now i cant see the image, so i cant really really help u, sorry.